# Multibyte character representation ASCII&Hex

Tags: c, ascii, asciiencoding

I'm having trouble to understand how multibyte character are represented in the ascii table : decimal format and then in hexadecimal.

For instance:

```
char *c = "é";
printf("%d\n%d", c[0], c[1]);
```

It will display :

```
-61

-87
```

In the ascii table, "é" in decimal is 130, and 82 in hex.
I understand 82 is the hexadecimal value of 130, but how can we obtain 130 from -61 & -87 ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my spelling

Comment: what happens when you cast your chars as `unsigned int`s and use `ud` as the `printf` modifier? Also note that `c[1]` is obviously going to show your `'\0'`

Comment: Error: Cast from pointer to integer. "é" must in a char *, can't be contained in a char, therefore an int either I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to UTF-8 charset (used, among other, by many GNU/Linux distributions), the value of `'é'` character constant is `0xC3A9`, which is equivalent to `11000011 10010101` in binary. Here we can understand the results, assuming two complement representation.

- The sequence `11000011` is equal to `-61` in decimal.
- The sequence `10010101` is equal to `-87` in decimal.

Comment: Well this is a real answer. I'm assuming Windows does not use this encoding?

Comment: I think Windows uses mainly Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: Thanks ! Now I just need to understand negative binary value conversion. Just to know, why in the ascii table its decimal value is 130 ?